# how do I make two internal networks speak with one another

Tags: networking, iptables

I have two internal networks that are connected to each other

10.10.10.1 and 10.10.11.1

I am trying to make devices on the 10.10.10.1 network be able to access the devices on the 10.10.11.1 network and vice versa.

My questions is what is the networking term used to "bridge/route" traffic between the two networks making each other available to one another.

Also what is the process in getting this going using iptables?

Answer (score 4):

It is called forwarding. You need a router between them, which knows the routes to each of those networks (if it's directly connected to them, it knows the routes automatically). Also the client PCs default gateway (router also) needs to know the way (route) to them (via another router). If they are both connected to the same router, then they should see eachother fine without any other devices. If they are on separate routers, and each has an unused interface, you can connect the routers, and set up routes for the networks.

If you have more networks, and need the routers to be able to set up routes dynamically, you also need one of the routing protocols (RIP, OSPF, IS-IS,...).

You don't need iptables for routes and basic forwarding. You'd need iptables for NAT or firewall.

If you want a better answer, you should explain more (IPs with netmasks, and the connection scheme, what is connected to what and how, etc.).

Comment: The issue im having is the following. I am using ClearOS as my router and within that network (10.10.10.1/24) I have an OpenVPN Access Server( at 10.10.10.103) giving out 10.10.10.100-199 ips which when in Layer 3 (Routing/NAT) mode I cannot access the other peers of the 10.10.10.1 network. If I enable Layer 2 mode with Bridging I can access all peers on the network without a problem however it does not currently Support Mac clients. What i'd like to do is create a separate network in openvpn 10.10.11.0/24 for clients and make it able to view 10.10.10.0/24 network. Any suggestions?